# Comunicação JSON entre domínios com Cordova

Tags: jquery, android, apache-cordova, mobile, cordova-plugin

Necessito que a aplicação faça comunicação com um servidor via JSON para fazer login. Como fazer?

---

**Obs:**
Apenas uma comunicação simples via JSON utilizando Cordova, onde a resposta foi bem esclarecedora.

Comment: Você sabe alguma coisa sobre a tecnologia que pretende usar? Tem algum código com alguma coisa que já tenha feito?

Comment: Já foi respondida. Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra você se comunicar com um servidor, terá que já ter seu *backend* estruturado, após isso, basta fazer a requisição. Um exemplo usando jQuery e PHP:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'URLDOMEUARQUIVO.php',
   data: {
      email: $('#email').val(),
      senha: $('#senha').val()
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function(){
      alert('Carrengado...')
   },
   success: function(data){
      localStorage.setItem('id', data.id)
   }
})
```

Com o código acima, você está enviando uma requisição para o seu arquivo PHP solicitando as informações, caso o usuário exista, ele vai lhe retornar um JSON com os dados.

```
<?php
   $retorno = array();
   $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?");
   $sql->execute(array($_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']));
   
   if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
      $retorno['status'] = 1
      $retorno['dados'] = $sql->fetchAll();   
   }
   
   $retorno['status'] = 0

   die(json_encode($retorno));
```

E o código acima seria mais ou menos o comportamento do *backend*, claro que isso é só um exemplo e deve ser adaptado conforme sua vontade. Caso tenha alguma dificuldade, aconselho que veja [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwYri2322ZI&t=554s).